# Issue with Jquery to retrieve data from Json

Tags: jquery, json, getjson

This is the relevant JSON fragment:

```
"media$description":{
      "$t":"Lorem Ipsum sit amet dolore des sit mutinons",
      "type":"plain"
 },
```

when I do this:

```
$("#pics2").html("Description: " +
                 data.feed.entry[0].media$group.media$description.type);
```

I get: `Description plain`. But when I do this:

```
$("#pics2").html("Description: " +
                 data.feed.entry[0].media$group.media$description.$t);
```

I get: `Description undefined`. I need to get the text "Lorem Ipsum..."

**Solved:** I was tweaking someone else's code, and I did no realize tat I was accessing the wrong json data set (with identical structures).

Comment: There must be some other context your not telling us about, because this works perfectly as you can see [at this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c27xm/).

Comment: did u try `['$t']` instead of `.$t`

Comment: @chad thank you, you helped me realize i was querying the wrong data (same structure) I was pulling my hair out.!!